# PHP & MySQL. Пользователи и записи

Tags: php, mysql

Имеется 2 таблицы с пользователями (100+) и с какими-либо записями(1000+).
на php реализован просмотр этих записей для разных пользователей.
задача реализовать  для каждого отдельного пользователя  статусы для всех записей просмотрено и не просмотрено.
В принципе можно хранить у каждого пользователя список просмотренных(или не***) соответственно остальные буду не просмотренные (просмотренные) 
Есть ли какие-нибудь оптимальные пути решения? и какие?

Answer (score 2):

```
         ____________________________________________________
        |                       USERS                        |
        | ___________________________________________________|
     PK |  id                                                |<——————————|
     U  |  login                                             |           |
        |  ...                                               |           |
        |  password                                          |           |
        |                                                    |           |
        |____________________________________________________|           |
                                                                         |  
         ____________________________________________________            |
        |                       RECORDS                      |           |
        | ___________________________________________________|           |
     PK |  id                                                |<——|       |
        |  name                                              |   |       |
        |  ...                                               |   |       |
        |  content                                           |   |       |
        |                                                    |   |       |
        |____________________________________________________|   |       |
         ____________________________________________________    |       |
        |                   VISITED_RECORDS                  |   |       |
        | ___________________________________________________|   |       |
     FK |  user_id                                           |———|       |
     FK |  record_id                                         |———————————|
        |  visit_dtime                                       |
        |                                                    |
        |____________________________________________________|
```

Comment: @uzumaxy вы похоже на картинке стрелки перепутали.

Comment: а если кроме просмотра к примеру будет еще статус "изменено" еще 1 таблицу делать для изменений

Comment: Нет, не перепутал. Каждый рисует как ему удобно. Благо, relation не однонаправленный.

Comment: Тогда да, создайте еще одну таблицу, где будет указанно как минимум: ИД пользователя-инициатора внесения изменений в запись, ИД измененной записи, дата модификации.

Answer (score 0):

да к записи  если запись кто-то поменял то у всех остальных(юзеров) кроме того кто ее поменял у этой записи должен быть статус изменено у этой записи. история.. ну если измененную запись посмотрели то у нее соответственно становится статус просмотрено.